# arrays elements and pointer references to them

Tags: c++, c

Say I have an array of n elements and also I have a pointer reference to one of the elements. Based solely on this information is it possible to find out the position of the element in the array?

Comment: Code speaks louder than words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure that the element is in the array, then yes, it is simple:

```
position = the_pointer - the_array;
// or
position = &the_reference - the_array;
```

If you aren't sure if the element is part of the array, then doing this may be undefined behavior.

There is no (standard approved) way to tell that the object you have a pointer or reference to is part of an array. So if you don't have access to the array, or aren't sure which array it is part of, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the address of the array is available, you can use pointer arithmetic.

```
int t[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *p = t + x; /* Where `x` is the given offset */
```

Then:

```
#include <stddef.h>

ptrdiff_t y = p - t;
```

Next, `y` should be equal to `x`.